# Why doesn't my Rust code with dependent types compile?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, traits, dependent-type

Why doesn't my Rust code compile?

```rust
pub struct BinaryFormatWithoutFieldUid<'a, T>(pub &'a T);

pub struct BinaryFormatWithoutLength<'a, T>(pub &'a T);

pub trait Serialize {}

impl<'a, T> Serialize for BinaryFormatWithoutFieldUid<'a, T>
    where BinaryFormatWithoutLength<'a, T>: Serialize
{}

impl<'a, T> Serialize for BinaryFormatWithoutFieldUid<'a, Option<T>>
    where BinaryFormatWithoutFieldUid<'a, T>: Serialize
{}

impl<'a, T> Serialize for BinaryFormatWithoutLength<'a, Option<T>>
    where BinaryFormatWithoutLength<'a, T>: Serialize
{}
```

```
error[E0275]: overflow evaluating the requirement `BinaryFormatWithoutLength<'_, std::option::Option<_>>: Serialize`
   |
   = help: consider increasing the recursion limit by adding a `#![recursion_limit = "256"]` attribute to your crate (`xrpl_async`)
note: required for `BinaryFormatWithoutLength<'_, std::option::Option<std::option::Option<_>>>` to implement `Serialize`
  --> src/lib.rs:15:13
   |
15 | impl<'a, T> Serialize for BinaryFormatWithoutLength<'a, Option<T>>
   |             ^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: 127 redundant requirements hidden
   = note: required for `BinaryFormatWithoutLength<'_, std::option::Option<std::option::Option<std::option::Option<...>>>>` to implement `Serialize`
   = note: the full type name has been written to '/home/porton/Projects/bugs/rust-overflow/target/debug/deps/xrpl_async-97a5b377c31d9cdb.long-type-8508140246639481262.txt'

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0275`.
error: could not compile `xrpl_async` due to previous error
```

I wrote the code to downstep from `Option<T>` to `T` in type arguments, but in a reason that I don't understand, Rust started to add more and more `Option<Option<...>>`. Why?

A funny thing is that commenting out any of the three last definitions makes the file compile. That's outrageous, have I found a bug in Rust?

rustc 1.67.1 (d5a82bbd2 2023-02-07)

Comment: I reported compiler bug: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/108637

Comment: I first thought it might be a case of [this](/q/66631251/2189130) which is a known compiler bug, but it is specific to constraints with lifetimes and [your code produces the same error without lifetimes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7569d4bcd1cb76bf46f92b9fdd4653b1). I think the compiler is unable to verify that your two `Serialize` implementations on `BinaryFormatWithoutFieldUid` do not conflict. And frankly neither am I.

Comment: @kmdreko If the issue were that the compiler were unable to verify that your two `Serialize` implementations on `BinaryFormatWithoutFieldUid` do not conflict, then removal of the last definition would not eliminate the error.

Comment: I don't think its as simple as you suggest. Without the last definition the compiler *knows* its not implemented using `Option<_>` since dependent crates could not create such an implementation. However, with the last definition, the compiler does *not know* whether there is an implementation using `Option<T>` because an implementation using `T` *can* be implemented in dependent crates. Thus the implementations on `BinaryFormatWithoutFieldUid` can conflict.

Comment: @kmdreko Got your point, it may be not a compiler bug but a deliberate behavior. However, what should I do with my code? How to make it work?

Comment: That would depend on the larger problem you are trying to solve with these definitions and traits. Its not clear from the struct names alone what you want to achieve.